# assigning a value to a global variable (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I am trying to access a global variable on a form that is one in an Array of Forms, I have tried using this:

```
max_forms := 3

setlength(form_array, max_forms);

form_array[1] := frm1;
form_array[2] := frm2;

if current_form > 0 then
begin
  form_array[current_form].fNumber := Number;
  form_array[current_form].ShowModal;
end;
```

The above does not work obviously.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear from that snippet exactly what isn't working. Are you getting a compile error? or is it crashing when you run? Could you explain what some of the variables are for and how they're defined?

Comment: You should also probably check that `current_form < max_forms` to prevent an array bounds check problem.

Comment: Hi

Sorry about that, to expand a bit I have a global variable on all the sub forms called FNumber, which i need to carry through from the main form.  The sub form number depends on a value which is stored in the database.  I have not run the code but I know its wrong simply because FNumber does not appear in the drop down after form_array[current_form].

Comment: Ah, OK. In that case DR's answer should do what you want

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that `fNumber` has private access.

Depending on the purpose of this field, one solution could be creating a property to gain write access:

```
property Number: Integer read FNumber write FNumber;
```

Then you can do the assignment:

```
form_array[current_form].Number := Number;
```

**About *global* variables:**

If this is in fact the problem and `FNumber` is the "global" variable you are talking about, then you are using the wrong words. `FNumber` is a field and belongs to a form. Form members are not global.

Look at the source of your form. If it has been generated by the Delphi IDE you'll find a variable declaration below it:

```
end; // End of TForm1

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
```

`Form1` is a real global variable, because it exists in the interface of a unit and outside of any class and you can access from anywhere (not a good thing in general) as for `FNumber` you first need access to a form instance.

PS:
I don't know what exactly you are trying to achive, but perhaps you can take a look at `Screen.Forms` which provides a list of the active forms. That might be better suited than a custom list.

Comment: Ok so I have'nt really used property before (I know, I'm still a newbie) any ideas on which unit I should set it up on?

Comment: It has to be in the same class as the field you access, in your case in the form and in the public part.

Comment: Explanation of the property keyword: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Property

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use the Tag property of the form...It's a scratch pad for you to store integer values...or anything from objects(.tag := integer(MyObject)) and integers...

```
max_forms := 3

setlength(form_array, max_forms);

form_array[1] := frm1;
form_array[2] := frm2;

if current_form > 0 then
begin
  form_array[current_form].Tag:= Number;
  form_array[current_form].ShowModal;
end;
```